# Creating a MouseEvent to make Cards clickable in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have been working on creating a game of Set with JavaFX. Currently, I am not sure how to make the individual Card Panes selectable/unselectable. When clicked, an individual card background should turn gray. And if clicked again, it should go back to white. I also need to keep track of whether or not a card is selected as I will then need to use it later to determine if three cards are a set.

Here is what I have so far for the code... Right now when you click, the entire background of the Center Pane turns gray and not the actual cards.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class GameFX extends Application {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Application.launch((String[]) args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Variables
        Game g = new Game();
        Board b = g.getBoard();
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        BackgroundFill grayBG = new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, new CornerRadii(1), new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        BackgroundFill darkGrayBG = new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKGRAY, new CornerRadii(1), new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(main);
        Label label = new Label("Set Game");
        Label instructionsLabel = new Label("Click on cards to select them, type 'A' to add three cards, type 'E' to end the game");
        Label actionsLabel = new Label("(A)dd 3 cards, (E)nd Game");
        Label cardsRemaining = new Label("There are " + "X " + "cards remaining in the deck");
        GridPane topPane = new GridPane();
        GridPane centerPane = new GridPane();
        GridPane rightPane = new GridPane();
        GridPane bottomPane = new GridPane();

        boolean stop = false;

        // Configure pane
        pane.setPrefHeight(500);
        pane.setPrefWidth(1000);
        centerPane.setPrefHeight(500);
        centerPane.setPrefWidth(700);
        rightPane.setPrefWidth(300);
        rightPane.setPrefHeight(500);
        pane.setBackground(new Background(grayBG));
        rightPane.setBackground(new Background(darkGrayBG));

        // Create initial board
        updateBoard(b, centerPane);

        // Configure label
        label.setTextFill(Color.RED);

        // Add content to topPane
        topPane.add(label, 0, 0);
        topPane.add(instructionsLabel, 0, 1);
        topPane.add(actionsLabel, 0, 2);
        topPane.add(cardsRemaining, 0, 3);

        // Set panes in BorderPane layout
        main.setCenter(centerPane);
        main.setTop(topPane);
        //main.setRight(rightPane);

        //test
        centerPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
               centerPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
               if(me.getClickCount() == 2){
                  centerPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
               }
            }
        });

        // Request focus and configure window
        stage.setTitle("Set");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        centerPane.requestFocus();
        centerPane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case A: {
                    System.out.println("A was pressed");
                    if (b.numCols() < 6) {
                        g.add3();
                    }
                    updateBoard(b, centerPane);
                    break;
                }
                case E: {
                  Platform.exit();
                  break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public static Pane createCard(int shape, int fill, int color, int number) {
         Pane cardPane = new Pane();
         Pane shapePane = new Pane();

         ArrayList<Rectangle> squares = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
         ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
         ArrayList<Rectangle> diamonds = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();


         String stripesRedURL = "stripesRed.png";
         String stripesPurpleURL = "stripesPurple.png";
         String stripesGreenURL = "stripesGreen.png";
         Image stripesRed = new Image(stripesRedURL);
         Image stripesPurple = new Image(stripesPurpleURL);
         Image stripesGreen = new Image(stripesGreenURL);

        BackgroundFill cardBG = new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE,
                new CornerRadii(1),
                new Insets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

         if (shape == 0) {
             for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
                 circles.add(new Circle(50,20 + (i * 30),10));
             }

             for(Circle circle: circles) {
                 if (fill == 0) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         circle.setFill(Color.RED);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         circle.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 1) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesPurple, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesGreen, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 2) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         circle.setStroke(Color.RED);
                         circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         circle.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
                         circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         circle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                         circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(circles);
             for(Circle circle: circles) {
                 shapePane.getChildren().add(circle);
             }
         } else if (shape == 1) {
             for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
                 squares.add(new Rectangle(40, 10 + (i * 30), 20, 20));
             }

             for(Rectangle square: squares) {
                 if (fill == 0) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         square.setFill(Color.RED);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         square.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         square.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 1) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         square.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         square.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesPurple, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         square.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesGreen, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 2) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         square.setStroke(Color.RED);
                         square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         square.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
                         square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         square.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                         square.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(squares);
             for(Rectangle square: squares) {
                 shapePane.getChildren().add(square);
             }
         } else if (shape == 2) {
             for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
                 diamonds.add(new Rectangle(40, 10 + (i * 30), 20, 20));
             }

             for(Rectangle diamond: diamonds) {
                 diamond.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45,50,50));
                 if (fill == 0) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         diamond.setFill(Color.RED);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         diamond.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         diamond.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 1) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         diamond.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         diamond.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         diamond.setFill(new ImagePattern(stripesRed, 0, 0, 40, 40, false));
                     }
                 } else if (fill == 2) {
                     if (color == 0) {
                         diamond.setStroke(Color.RED);
                         diamond.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 1) {
                         diamond.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
                         diamond.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     } else if (color == 2) {
                         diamond.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                         diamond.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                 }

             }
             System.out.println(diamonds);
             for(Rectangle diamond: diamonds) {
                 shapePane.getChildren().add(diamond);
             }
         }
        cardPane.setBackground(new Background(cardBG));
        cardPane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
        cardPane.setPrefHeight(100);
        cardPane.setPrefWidth(100);
                cardPane.getChildren().addAll(shapePane);
        return cardPane;

     }

     public void updateBoard(Board b, GridPane pane) {
         ArrayList<ArrayList<BoardSquare>> boardSquares = b.getBoardSquares();
         System.out.println(boardSquares);

         for (ArrayList<BoardSquare> boardRow: boardSquares) {
             for (BoardSquare boardSquare: boardRow) {
                 Card boardCard = boardSquare.getCard();
                 pane.add(createCard(boardCard.getShape(), boardCard.getShading(), boardCard.getColor(), boardCard.getNumber() + 1), boardSquare.getRow(), boardSquare.getColumn());
             }

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I recommend looking into using LWJGL for this task in specific because it will provide you with Keyboard tracking and Mouse tracking with ease to setup. Along with helping you in Animations in the end of your project development. LWJGL: https://www.lwjgl.org/

Comment: Another possible way to complete this is by making a Card class that extends pane, and give it methods that toggle selection.

Comment: @kixkid229 I could be wrong, but I don't think your suggestion works well with `JavaFX`.

Comment: You need to do something like `cardPane.setOnMouseClicked(me->{if(cardPane.getStyle() == null){cardPane.setStyle("-fx-...");}else{cardPane.setStyle(null);}     });`

Comment: Why not try to add event handlers to the cards and then post what you tried if it doesn't work?